# Aligning textfield and a button side by side in the same line

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I need to position a textfield and a button side by side always.The logic is something like this-The button will always be in the right side of the screen.The textfield should occupy the rest of the width in the left side.I tried giving a specific % width for the textfield.But I have to support both android and iOS devices.So there is a problem of varying screen sizes among them and that solution did not work well with all the screen sizes.This is the code I have used

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your user name"></input>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="normalBtn" style="margin-top:0px">Check</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/d7T4E/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try with this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
        <div style="display:inline;">
            <input type="text" style="width:50% !important; float:left;" placeholder="Enter your user name"></input><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" class="normalBtn" style="margin-top:0px; float:left;">Check</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But thats not what I am looking for because I want the textfield to take up the full width except the space needed for the button.